# Navigation View Below DrawerLayout

Tags: android, navigationview

hi i have a navigation view  with a drawer layout i want to looks like [image: this] but mine is look like [image]

and this is my code

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/activity_multi_tab"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"

        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift your navigation view inside the DrawerLayout but below the included layout.

Navigation view has to be the second child of DrawerLayout

Also change the layout gravity to start.

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

And remove the margin top. There'll otherwise be a space at the top

Refer this official documentation for more details on the view

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html

Comment: you mean like my new edit? @Kushan because this not work too

Comment: Yea, but change the layout gravity to start and remove margin top, itll look weird with margin top

Comment: Check out my new answer. If it still doesn't work, please reply asap, it's very late here and i need to sleep :)

Comment: idont know why but i change the gravity but its looks like the same and coming from right and match parent and thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: Try removing your header layout once... And check if any of your dependencies are forcing rtl view. Also in your developer options of your phone confirm if force rtl isn't turned on... It shouldn't be shown on the right now... Sorry man this is all i can think of right now

Comment: im so dumb i change the small screen size and my phone is medum im so sorry

Comment: Haha np mate :) enjoy coding... Tc n accept the answer if it helped :) gn buddy :)